# onPressed takes 2 clicks to complete nested functions

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

When a user enters their information in an overlay, presses submit, 4 things should happen.

1. User's account is registered in firestore
2. User has a document created with their info
3. the overlay is closed
4. nav() page is called

On the first click, **[1]** happens and then stops at the collection reference.
On the second click, **[1]** fails, but **[2-4]** successfully go through.  I think it has to do with when the user info not coming back from the registry fast enough but the prints are coming back correctly so I'm not sure.

**onPressed function in overlay**

```
onPressed: () async{
    await register(_email, _password);
    await signUp(_email, firstName, lastName, userName);
    hideNewUserOverlay();
    var navTab = 2;
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const Nav(),
        settings: RouteSettings(arguments: navTab)
    ));
```

}

**Register and Sign Up**

```
Future<void> register(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password); // <-- user account is created on first press
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('>> register: create new user error');
  }
  user = auth.currentUser!;
  debugPrint('   register: current user got');
  String userID = user.uid;
  debugPrint('   register: user.id = $userID');
}

Future<void> signUp(
    String email, String firstName, String lastName, String userName) async {
  user = auth.currentUser!;
  debugPrint('>> signUp: current user got');
  String userID = user.uid;
  debugPrint('   signUp: user.id = $userID'); // all debugs print out correctly

  try {
    debugPrint('   signUp: document creation code Start');
    await collectionReference.doc(userID).set({ // first click stops here, takes 2 clicks to finish
      'profileImageUrl': 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/commentaries-d82cd.appspot.com/o/defaultProfileImage.png?alt=media&token=07e4d649-3da7-4f9f-8cf9-062ac9cc9507',
      'userID': userID,
      'accountCreated': DateTime.now(),
      'email': email,
      'userName': userName,
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
    });
    debugPrint('   signUp: User Document Created');
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('   signUp: create new user error');
  }
}
```

Comment: You use nested .then calls, try to convert them to `await` calls instead.

Comment: I have tried that, I get the same error.  It has to be something in the functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't work all at once because you are making asynchronous calls but your `onPressed` function is not `async`

Try this:

```
onPressed: () async{
    await register(_email, _password);
    await signUp(_email, firstName, lastName, userName);
    hideNewUserOverlay();
    var navTab = 2;
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => const Nav(),
      settings: RouteSettings(arguments: navTab)
   ));
 }
```

Comment: I'm now using your code, copy paste.  It's still taking two button clicks, not sure why but this looks a lot neater at least.

Comment: And if you add `async` in the `signUp` function ?
```
Future<void> signUp async{
... some code
}
```

Comment: Async is on signup, it's just on the next line the formatting got messed up

Answer (score 1):

You can add callback to your functions, so you know they are done.
See:

```
    Future<void> register(String email, String password, VoidCallback callback) async {
  try {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password); // <-- user account is created on first press
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('>> register: create new user error');
  }
  user = auth.currentUser!;
  debugPrint('   register: current user got');
  String userID = user.uid;
  debugPrint('register: user.id = $userID');
  callback(); //here you will send the flag informing the job is done.

}
```

Now let´s do the same with the other function.

```
    Future<void> signUp(
    String email, String firstName, String lastName, String userName, VoidCallback callback) async {
  user = auth.currentUser!;
  debugPrint('>> signUp: current user got');
  String userID = user.uid;
  debugPrint('   signUp: user.id = $userID'); // all debugs print out correctly

  try {
    debugPrint('   signUp: document creation code Start');
    await collectionReference.doc(userID).set({ // first click stops here, takes 2 clicks to finish
      'profileImageUrl': 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/commentaries-d82cd.appspot.com/o/defaultProfileImage.png?alt=media&token=07e4d649-3da7-4f9f-8cf9-062ac9cc9507',
      'userID': userID,
      'accountCreated': DateTime.now(),
      'email': email,
      'userName': userName,
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
    });
    debugPrint('   signUp: User Document Created');
    callback();
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('   signUp: create new user error');
  }
}
```

now you can make this with steps:

```
onPressed: () async{
await register(_email, _password, (){
   await signUp(_email, firstName, lastName, userName, (){
       hideNewUserOverlay();
       var navTab = 2;
       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => const Nav(),
         settings: RouteSettings(arguments: navTab)
        ));
   });
});

}
```

Explaination: What I did was to place the next step inside the callback. So, you know everything will continue only when you really want it to.
next things to do to make your code better:

- Named paramters to help code reading.
- Create functions to callbacks, making the code more readable too and maintenable.
- remove the awaits no more needed.
- Create a Loading while the process go, as this can take long.
- Create a block to not allow multiples clicks in this button.
- Create callbacks to handle failures.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this advice does not target my specific issue.  I know when the functions are completing, I have debug statements inside the function that will let me know when it gets to the end or not.  This is helpful, but I still need help with the issue at hand.